# What is the best Windows Server 2008 configuration for a .NET development environment?

Tags: .net, windows-server-2008

I want to give Windows Server 2008 a try as a .NET developer and a database environment.

I was wondering which configuration would be the most appropriate for the server in terms of:

- **Services:** Which ones are unnecessary and can be turned off to increase performance?
- **Software:** What software fits the best with the server and are good to increase developing scope (Sharepoint, SQL Server, VS2008, Azure)?
- **Tweaks:** I know there is a [tool](http://www.win2008workstation.com/wordpress/) to make the server more like a workstation. Is there anything else that is similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually a default install of Windows Server 2008 doesn't have many services running to start with.  Just add the roles you need to test your projects.

If you want to minimize the number of running services then you don't want to tweak the server into a workstation.

Answer (score 1):

And don't forget.  64-bit!  Cram the thing with as much RAM as it will take!

Answer (score 0):

Don't activate Superfetch. It will load you disk with work for many long minutes each time the system starts.

Don't add "Widows Resource Manager" feature, which sounds attractive from its description. It will bring permanent CPU load in the range of 8-12%.